# Expected identifier/parse issue in xcode?

Tags: xcode, if-statement

Im creating an ios app in xcode, and I keep getting this error. Here is my code:

```
          If (myGlobal ==1) {
          }
```

What is wrong? Im sorry i do not know how to properly do the code, i am a beginner and am just looking for help. Please dont mark my post down, I just started with this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure If is not capitalized. It should be all lowercase "if".
2. Make sure myGlobal has been declared.
3. If myGlobal is a property try using self.myGlobal instead.

Otherwise you will need to post the myGlobal declaration to us.